# Error running a pygame script with python

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting a problem whilst following https://dr0id.bitbucket.io/legacy/pygame_tutorial01.html this tutorial.

I was trying to write this code :

```
import os
import pygame     

image = pygame.image.load("Screenshot_2.png")    
screen.blit(image, (50, 50))   
pygame.display.flip()  
 
def main():
    pygame.init()

    logo = pygame.image.load("Screenshot_1.png")
    pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
    pygame.display.set_caption("minimal program") 

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((240,180))

    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

and it comes out with the error "NameError: name 'screen' is not defined". Can someone help?

Comment: It's explained how to create the screen variable in the previous tutorial: https://dr0id.bitbucket.io/legacy/pygame_tutorial00.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the display before attempting to `blit` anything on it. So `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((240,180))` has to be called before drawing anthing.

Furthermore, the typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

```py
import os
import pygame     
 
def main():
    pygame.init()

    logo = pygame.image.load("Screenshot_1.png")
    pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
    pygame.display.set_caption("minimal program") 

    # initialize a window or screen for display
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((240,180))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    image = pygame.image.load("Screenshot_2.png")    

    # main application loop
    running = True
    while running:

        # event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # clear the display
        screen.fill(0)

        # draw the scene   
        screen.blit(image, (50, 50)) 

        # update the display
        pygame.display.flip()  

        # limit frames per second
        clock.tick(100)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```